# Why is EF treating a char property as an actual guid?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

What I have actually is a property of type char which I use to store the string value of a guid.

My current setup:
- MySQL
- EF Code-First
- EF Migration

Model:

```
public class Employee  
{  
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

EF config

```
public class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Employee>  
{  
    public EmployeeConfiguration()  
    {  
        HasKey(x => x.Id);  
        Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasColumnType(“char”)
            .HasMaxLength(36)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);  
    }  
}
```

The problem:
System.FormatException is thrown if I do the following:
1. Insert with an Id that doesn’t follow the format of a guid.
2. Querying the above Employee class from database that contains an Id that doesn’t follow the format of a guid.

If I try to insert or query straight to the database using sql (without using EF), it’s all fine. 
Can you please guide me how to work around this problem?

Edit 1:
Error message

> Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

**Solution that worked for me**
From "Jason Armstrong" suggestion, I used a different char length, I went with a char(37).

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Are you sure it’s not your own code that’s throwing the exception? You say you are using this property to store a guid. Are you converting the property to/from actual guid type somewhere in your code?

Comment: I can’t now, I am still on my way home from work.. i will give you that tomorrow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EntityFramework automatically maps CHAR(36) TO GUID for MySQL per [Entity Framework Data Type Mapping](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/datatypemapping.html)

Try adding `old guids=true` to your connection string per [C# & MySQL Connector: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes](https://www.christianroessler.net/tech/2015/c-sharp-mysql-connector-guid-should-contain-32-digits-with-4-dashes.html)

Comment: That’s interesting but I just have one question regarding that solution. Besides the Id property that I have, I am also using a RowVersion property of type System.Guid as EF’s concurrency token. Since I will be instructing EF to interpret guids as System.String, I am guesing it would also affect EF’s interpretation of my RowVersion property?..

Comment: I’m not aware of any way to disable the auto mapping on a case by case basis. One other option is to use CHAR(37), annoying, but it would get the job done.

Comment: Interesting, can’t wait to try your suggestions tomorrow. Will update you tomorrow ASAP thanks ^_^

Comment: hi. i am trying out your suggestion now but its not working. old guids is supposed to be one word (oldguids) but doesn't work. if i update the database using migration, visual studio crashes. if i make the length anything other than 36, i get the same error as before, EF complains when i use a non-guid formatted string

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change one Id property to a new length. I take back my last comment. My code is working now. Thank you so much.